# Comparison of bond length between sulfur tetrafluoride and selenium tetrafluoride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

> Compare the bond lengths for selenium tetrafluoride, $x = d(\ce{Se-F})$, and sulfur tetrafluoride, $y = d(\ce{S-F})$: 
>   (a) $x > y$ (b) $y > x$ (c) $x =y$ (d) none of those.

Since selenium is bigger in size compared to sulfur, therefore the $\ce{Se-F}$ bond in $\ce{SeF4}$ would be shorter in length compared to $\ce{S-F}$ bond in $\ce{SF4}$, thus $y > x$.

But the book says $x > y$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bond length is measured from nucleus to nucleus, not from ‘where the core shells end’ or ‘behind the valence electrons’ — these are not defined, you might as well measure to the end of the rainbow. The positions of nuclei can relatively precisely be determined by X-ray crystallography so you have something you can measure.

Naturally, the larger atom must have longer bonds.